Python/ iogram| Выводит данные только из первой строки таблицы Базы данных sqlite3
Пишу бота TG iogram3. Проблема в том , что из DB (sqlite) в чат выводится только первая строка из таблицы, хотя в самой БД строк 4. Помогите пожалуйста, не могу найти причину.


Код handlers.py
from aiogram.types import Message
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart

import app.keyboard as kb


router = Router()


@router.message(CommandStart())
async def cmd_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Добро пожаловать!', reply_markup=kb.main)


@router.message(F.text == 'Каталог')
async def catalog(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Выберите вариант из каталога', reply_markup=await kb.categories())


@router.callback_query(F.data.startswith('category_'))
async def category_selected(message: Message):
    category_id = message.data.split('_')[1]
    await message.answer(f'Вы выбрали категорию {category_id}')

Код models.py
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, Mapped, mapped_column, DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncAttrs, async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine

from config import SQLALCHEMY_URL

engine = create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_URL, echo=True)
async_session = async_sessionmaker(engine)


class Base(AsyncAttrs, DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    tg_id = mapped_column(BigInteger)


class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    products = relationship('Product', back_populates='category')


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    description: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    price: Mapped[int] = mapped_column()
    category_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey('categories.id'))
    category = relationship('Category', back_populates='products')


async def async_main():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

Код keyboard.py
from aiogram.types import ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardButton
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder

from app.database.requests import get_categories

main = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=[
    [KeyboardButton(text='Каталог')],
    [KeyboardButton(text='Контакты')]
], resize_keyboard=True, input_field_placeholder='Выберите пункт ниже')


async def categories():
    categories_kb = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    categories = await get_categories()
    for category in categories:
        categories_kb.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=category.name, callback_data=f'category_{category.id}'))
        return categories_kb.adjust(2).as_markup()

Код requests.py
from app.database.models import User, Category, Product, async_session
from sqlalchemy import select


async def get_categories():
    async with async_session() as session:
        result = await session.scalars(select(Category))
        return result


return categories_kb.adjust(2).as_markup() — ну вы завершаете работу функции сразу после добавления первой строки, вот только одна строка и остаётся

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить? На что заменить код, никак понять не могу

Ещё раз всё проверил, + сам код , это видео обучение по созданию Телеграм бота и у автора строка return categories_kb.adjust(2).as_markup() прописана и с ней всё работает. Вообще понять ничего не могу ( Где у меня не так

Может кто-то смоет на пальцах объяснить как сделать чтобы выдавались все строки с БД?

вызывай return после окончания цикла, а не внутри его
